# How to make rundeck CLI tools connect using localhost?

Tags: rundeck

I've [read](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/development/docs/en/manpages/man1/authentication.md) that the rundeck CLI tools (rd-project, etc.) use `framework.properties` to find the URL to connect to rundeck from or environment variables. I just can't get anything to work.

I need to make it connect via `127.0.0.1:4440`. I can telnet to this port and I know it's OK. However, I can't telnet to `1.2.3.4:4440` from the instance (where `1.2.3.4` is the public IP). I can't find how to configure AWS security groups correctly.

I've changed `framework.properties` as follows:

```
...
framework.server.url = http://127.0.0.1:4440
```

I reloaded rundeck, but this makes no difference. `rd-project` still fails to connect. It fails even if I change `framework.server.name` and `framework.server.hostname` to my public IP and restart.

Using the environment variable `RUNDECK_URL` makes no difference. I'm using v2.6.2.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my command:

```
RUNDECK_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4440 /usr/bin/rd-project -a create -p newProj
```

Comment: You dont have to change the "framework.server.url", just make sure you have correct "framework.server.username" and "framework.server.password"... or try giving them as env.. RUNDECK_URL=http://rundeck_host:4440/ RUNDECK_USER=admin RUNDECK_PASS=admin rd-jobs list -p project_name .. this would work

Comment: As I wrote, I tried setting `RUNDECK_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4440` but it didn't work.

Comment: what output on shell you are getting while running the following.. "RUNDECK_URL=rundeck_host:4440 RUNDECK_USER=admin RUNDECK_PASS=admin rd-jobs list -p project_name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the following properties to config rundeck for localhost:

In framework.properties:

framework.server.hostname=localhost

In rundeck-config.properties:

grails.serverURL=http://localhost:[port]

Hope this helps.